# How to automatically remap application using a script file and Haproxy?

Tags: linux, haproxy

I have asked the same question before but i din't get any answers for it.I know how to manually map applications listening on various ports to Specific Url. For example, adding the below Haproxy configuration will let me map the URL http://206.189.22.155:30000/designer-api/ to URL http://206.189.22.155/designer-api/.

haproxy configuration used for mapping URL

```
frontend http-in
    mode    http

    bind 206.189.22.155:80

    acl path-page-designer              path_beg -i /designer-api/
    use_backend page-designer-backend   if path-page-designer

backend page-designer-backend
    mode    http

    option  httplog
    option  forwardfor

    server  appserver1 206.189.22.155:30000
```

So this works perfectly fine.But now I want to take a step further in automating this.How to write a script that can remap the ports automatically.I mean rather than configuring this manually in the haproxy.cfg, the mapping has to be done dynamically because later i will integrate the script into azure release pipelines.

Comment: Lack of information. But basically you're asking about Lua scripting inside haproxy or the software similar to HTTP edge routers like traefik. I don't like to guess.

Comment: i was asking about  Lua scripting inside haproxy ?

Comment: Basically i want this script to be invoked from the azure release pipeline

Comment: all the application specific details like port , /servicename etc should be sent to this script as a parameter from the pipeline configuration!!

Comment: so how can i automatically remap the url this way ?